# Does subnet mask matter for router?

Tags: networking, router, subnet

First let me say that I'm new to networking. But if i have servers with 10.0.0.47 (/8) subnet masks which gives me enough for host addresses, do i have to assigned my router interface a (/8) subnet mask as well?
If i understand correctly the router uses subnet mask to check which network does the ip address belongs to?

I tried testing on packet tracer assigning (/24) subnet mask to for all router interface:

```
Server1 has 10.0.0.47/8 connected to the g0/0 (10.0.0.1/24)

PC1 has 192.168.0.30/24 connected to g0/1 (192.168.0.1/24)
```

When I ping the server1 with pc1 it was successful, does that mean that the router interface doesnt need to share the same subnet mask with the devices?

Comment: For the `192.168.0.X` PC subnet the router just needs to know where to point to for the different subnet on the `10.0.0.X` subnet since it's on a different subnet entirely the router routes between the subnets to get from one to the other. The server 1 may be on the `10.X.X.X` because the `10.0.0` first 3 octets match and it routable to it since g0/0 has a `10.0.0` first 3 octet IP even though the PC has a class A subnet, it's still routable because the first 3 octets match. If you assign Server2 and IP of `10.1.0.X` class A subnet IP, it'd be interesting to see if they can ping then.

Answer (score 3):

> But if i have servers with 10.0.0.47 (/8) subnet masks which gives me enough for host addresses, do i have to assigned my router interface a (/8) subnet mask as well? If i understand correctly the router uses subnet mask to check which network does the ip address belongs to?

Yes, all devices in a given subnet *including* routers need to agree on the subnet mask. A router behaves exactly the same way as a host as far as subnet routing is concerned (the only difference is that a router will forward packets it receives, a host won't).

> When I ping the server1 with pc1 it was successful, does that mean that the router interface doesnt need to share the same subnet mask with the devices?

Mismatching subnet masks will happen to work as long as they still result in the same routing decisions. (But "happens to work" doesn't mean the setup is correct.) The subnet mask doesn't actually go in packets and doesn't become part of an address – it is only used for a routing table lookup, the same as if you manually added an /8 or /24 "interface" route.

In your case, the server's IP address is still **within the router's 10.0.0.0/24** so it is correctly considered "on-link", the same way as it would be if the router had its interface as a /16 or /8. In other words, the automatically added `10.0.0.0/24 via g0/0` "directly connected" route still matches the destination IP address (take a look at `show ip route`).

But if the server's address had been 10.0.1.47 or 10.20.30.47, then the router would no longer have a route for it – packets would still be delivered in one direction (from server via router) but not from router to server. (And if the router had uRPF filtering enabled, it would reject packets from the server as well.)

You could *manually* define direct routes to cover the rest of the /8 and they would have the same effect as the interface's subnet mask, e.g. by using `ip route 10.0.0.0/8 g0/0` you would make the subnet work as expected, in an unnecessarily roundabout way. (Although it is still worth trying this in PT, to get a better understanding of how subnets work.)

Answer (score 0):

While it's good practice for all computer and routers to share the
same subnet, different subnets can work in a small local network (although not recommended).

Computers are found by MAC address via the
[Address Resolution Protocol (ARP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol).
In a nutshell, a computer that has a message for an IP broadcasts on
the entire network the ARP question "who has this IP".
Whatever computer has this IP (or knows which one has the IP) will respond.
From then on the communication path is established between the
two computers and the router.

The subnet has greater role when sending a message. A computer has
a network adapter that is identified by an IP and netmask and a gateway.
If a message is sent to an IP that does not fall inside the range
implied by this IP+netmask, the sending software will not find
this network adapter and the sending will fail without attempting to
find the computer with ARP.

A computer that receives a message will not check if its sender IP
falls within its IP range, but will simply act upon it.
It will not reject any message that is addressed to its own IP.

So in effect subnet mismatch can work in a local network,
especially when there is only one router, although this
can cause some failures that are not obvious to analyze when
messages are passed around.